# Trigger after insert, insert new row into another table

Tags: trigger, wordpress

I'm developing a Wordpress site. 
I'm trying to insert a new row into a table when new row with specific value in usermeta table is added.
This is what I got for now:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER user_sub AFTER INSERT ON wp_usermeta
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF meta_value='subscribe' THEN
INSERT INTO newsletter_user_list SET list_id = 1,user_id=NEW.user_id;
END IF;
END;
| 
DELIMITER ;
```

But this breaks the usermeta table. After new user register usermeta table is not populated.Thank you very much for any help because I have no experience with triggers.

Comment: Is this question about mysql?

Comment: Yes, it is about mysql.

Comment: `IF NEW.meta_value='subscribe' THEN`. Without specifying NEW pseudotable a literal `meta_value` is considered a variable name. Such variable is not declared, so error occures and trigger fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina)!

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER user_sub AFTER INSERT ON wp_usermeta
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.meta_value='subscribe' THEN
INSERT INTO newsletter_user_list SET list_id = 1,user_id=NEW.user_id;
END IF;
END;
| 
DELIMITER ;
```